# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library

Tags: python, anaconda

I am running PyTorch in Python 3.8.5 on a M1 Macbook Pro, and I get these error messages:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel(R) SSSE3) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
```

What do they mean, and what can I do to resolve them?

Comment: I was getting the same error messages the last few days (PyTorch had worked fine a week ago).  For me what has worked so far has been: make a new conda environment.  conda install nomkl.  pip install torch.  Doesn't feel robust, but wanted to pass it on.  The idea to use pip instead of conda was from https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/71022 These are just the random steps that worked (so far) for me.  I hope someone else gives a more correct answer.

Comment: I corrupted my conda env with the same error lately. I installed pytorch with some instructions for M1 I found online. Now anything I import raises this error. It is thrown  when I do any import in python: "Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library."

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this error when trying to install an intel env via `conda` on an M1 mac. With a native env (`osx-arm64`) it worked, but I needed an intel env (`osx-64`) for some other reason.

I managed to resolve this error by downgrading `mkl` to version 2021 instead of version 2022 which was installed as a transitive dependency.

I simply added this to my `environment.yml` and re-installed it:

```
- mkl < 2022
```

Note that if your `conda` is M1 native (i.e. has a platform of `osx-arm64`), and you want to install an intel environment, you need to do it like so:

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda env update -f environment.yml
```

The env also contains `pytorch`, and this approach allowed me to install everything via conda, instead of relying on a hybrid of conda/pip like the other solutions.

Comment: This was exactly my issue: using Torch in an `osx-64` environment on an Apple M2 chip. This worked for me. One small aside: If you don't want to add this permanently to your `environment.yml` (because you want it to be cross-platform), then you can just use the one-time command: `conda install -c conda-forge "mkl<2022"`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515117/how-to-set-up-a-conda-osx-64-environment-on-arm-mac) about creating Intel envs vs. AMD envs.

Answer (score 7):

As @CJD suggested installing PyTorch using pip apparently solves the problem, even on a Mac with M1 or newer versions M1 Pro and M1 Max [Tested].
Using `pip` will install PyTorch without MKL.

Steps:

1. Uninstall PyTorch using `conda` (if it is installed): `conda remove pytorch`
2. Install it using `pip`: `pip install torch` .

Check the following link for further details: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/71022

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error messages for any package I tried to import (ie, numpy, pandas, etc). I am running OSX Monterey on a late 2008 macbook 5,1 through opencore. The key bit for me was just installing nomkl as per CJD's comment above. It didn't matter whether it was a new or base environment. I don't really understand what the problem was or the possible limitations of the fix, but it is working now.

Comment: ähm - its working because python is running as INTEL not ARM - check with Activity Monitor.  I would have hoped pytorch is running native on arm64 architecture though..

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error when trying Huggingface models. M1 Mac with `conda` environment.

Apparently "problem" is that `conda` installs packages for M1 Mac (who would have thought, huh) but not every library works with arm processor. This seems to be the case with Torch library.

How I fixed this.

1. Created new env
2. With `pip install torch, torchvision`
3. `conda install` the rest of dependencies.

The problem might not be in Torch package itself but rather the way `conda` picks other dependencies. It looks for best ones for particular environment. On the other hand `pip` doesn't bother much to find most suitable ones particularly for arm processor and installs what works.