# conda env broken after installing pytorch on M1 - Intel MKL FATAL ERROR

Tags: pytorch, conda, apple-m1, intel-mkl

I installed `pytorch` on my M1 mac book, following some instructions on-line (via `conda` command). Then my whole environment got corrupted. Whenever I try to import some library (pandas, numpy, whatever) I get this:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel(R) SSSE3) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
```

1. How can I fix it?
2. How can I install pytorch successully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for me a few weeks ago:

1. Create a new conda environment and activate it.
2. `conda install ipykernel jupyter numpy pandas matplotlib nomkl` (the key part being to include `nomkl` and don't include PyTorch).
3. `pip install torch torchvision`

I could not get step 3 to work using conda (possibly related [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/71022)).

This doesn't feel like a robust solution (mixing conda and pip), but the environment has worked for me the past few weeks.

Comment: this one worked - not sure why but it did - there's definitely too many solutions available online to install python on M1 mac...

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately. When I do import torch python crashes with this error: ```'ipython' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)```

Comment: I didn't like the approach of adding `nomkl` just for macOS, and then needing to install torch separately with conda. [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640311/1230403) solved it for me using conda alone, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: The below hasn't worked for me; I just ended up using pip inside a conda env :(*

Conda's website includes a fix:

https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/index.html#uninstalling-mkl

> To opt out, run `conda install nomkl` and then use `conda install <packages>`

Also:

> If you are using OS X or Linux, have already installed these packages or already installed all of Anaconda, and wish to switch away from MKL, use the command `conda install nomkl numpy scipy scikit-learn numexpr` followed by `conda remove mkl mkl-service`