# segmentation fault python after import torch on mac M1

Tags: pytorch, segmentation-fault, conda, apple-m1

I struggled to install `pytorch` on my Mac M1 chip.

I fixed the previous issue with `mkl` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306262/conda-env-broken-after-installing-pythorch-on-m1-intel-mkl-fatal-error/71329843#71329843)

Now I do:

```
conda install ipykernel jupyter numpy pandas matplotlib nomkl 
pip install torch torchvision
python
import torch
```

and I get:

```
zsh:segmentation fault  python
```

from terminal, when I run jupyter - the kernel just crashes

how to fix it?

Comment: same here. any update

Answer (score 1):

its because of a numpy dependency conflict, try this one:
first import numpy, and then torch:

import numpy; import torch

Answer (score 0):

i just met this error, mac m1, python3.8 & pyTorch 1.14.

installed from this command:

*pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu*

and meet this error too.

The following command help's me to solve the problem

*conda install "libblas=*=*mkl"*

I refered this article:
*https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/66782*