# How to set up a conda osx-64 environment on ARM mac?

Tags: x86, conda, apple-m1, conda-forge, mamba

I have an M1 MacBook using conda through miniforge3.

I want to use a packages not built for ARM (ifcopenshell, pythonocc-core). Mixing channels (`conda-forge/osx-64` and `conda-forge/osx-arm`) often does not work reliably.

How do I tell conda/mamba to have an environment only using x64? I don't want to install osx-64 conda in parallel.

Comment: @merv,  you need to set `--env` to make that work only for that env. Otherwise it's a global setting.
`conda config --env --set subdir osx-64`

Comment: @isuruf oops good catch - was a little hasty there. I cover this setting here (though, for **win-32** / **win-64** switching): https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918

Answer (score 27):

```
  conda create -n intel_env
  conda activate intel_env
  conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
  conda install python
```

Or

```
  CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n intel_env python
  conda activate intel_env
  conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

Comment: This is the answer. Works for me and my environment is extremely complicated to configure.

Comment: Adding to this comment, this also helps: https://vineethbharadwaj.medium.com/m1-mac-switching-terminal-between-x86-64-and-arm64-e45f324184d9

Answer (score 3):

Using [`micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html) it's as simple as adding `--platform osx-64` to every invocation of `micromamba`:

`micromamba create -n intel_env --platform osx-64 python`

Micromamba is an alternative conda-env manager, supporting most conda commands with some slight differences. It's what's powering `mamba` v1 under the hood.