# unable to install Bioconda packages on Mac

Tags: conda, bioinformatics, apple-m1, bioconda

first time using command line and I am trying to install Bioconda packages (fastp and bowtie1) in my environment on a Mac w/ M1 chip but I continually get the same error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - fastp

Current channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Any advice helps, thank you!

Comment: As the error says, it is not available to run natively on your M1 (arm64), see [the website](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/fastp) which only lists x64 for mac. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515117/miniforge-3-on-arm-osx-mixing-x64-and-arm64-packages) on how to create an env that uses x64 packages

Answer (score 5):

Running this command on base worked for me:

```
conda config --add subdirs osx-64
```

Check: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11216