# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. (When importing numpy or pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I get this error when I import numpy or pandas.

[image]

I have tried every solution found in similar posts but was not successfull. I have downgraded or upgraded many libraries, but the problem is still there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run `import numpy` in the python interpreter directly?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that. I tried it and this is what I get

>>> import numpy
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel(R) SSSE3) instructions.
The processor must support the Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) instructions.

Apparently my processor is a little too old for this. Any workaround?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830755/intel-mkl-fatal-error-this-system-does-not-meet-the-minimum-requirements-for-us)?

Comment: Yes I saw that @mozway the same day I learned it was because of my processor.
When I entered "conda install nomkl" in my terminal, it took more than 24hrs to do the job and the whole time the CPU was more than 80% active. after 24hrs I terminated it, and now I am back to square one